# Django static page?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I want to make a static page which will be shown to the user only if he/she clicks on a link provided in one of my models. I can do this by making a Python page alone and calling it, but I want it be called from Django. The user interface should be constructed using the Django API only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? E.g. is the content of the static page required to be in the database or is it allowed to be in a file? Is it only logged-in users that are allowed to access the static page?

Answer (score 66):

With the class-based views in newer Django versions, one can use this in urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
url(r'^about', 
    TemplateView.as_view(template_name='path/to/about_us.html'),
    name='about'),
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer now supersedes Rubayeets.

Comment: `url(` should be `path(` no?

Answer (score 52):

Bypassing views to render a static template, add this line in "urls.py". For example "About Us" page could be

```
(r'^about', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'path/to/about_us.html'}),
```

Comment: Nice simple solution for when introducting flatpages is overkill

Comment: Function-based generic views have been deprecated from Django 1.5 onwards. Instead, use class-based views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: The link suggested by George P Burdell is not accessible now, use this link instead (for django 1.11): [Class-based views] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/)

Answer (score 13):

Do you mean something like Django's [flatpages app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/)?  It does exactly what you describe.

Comment: The only tiny inconvenience with that (for small indie projects, I guess) is... it's advantage — page is stored in DB, thus it will not migrate to prod with your code. But anyway, once it's in the DB, it's easy to maintain it in the /admin.

Comment: Nah, switching back to git'able version, because of versioning.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a static page the [flatpages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) is a good choice. It allows you to easily create static content. Creating static content is not harder than creating a view really.

Answer (score 1):

On Django 2.2.6, loosely following David's answer, I added the path in **urls.py**:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    .... .... ....
    path('about',
         TemplateView.as_view(template_name='path/to/about_us.html'),
         name='about'),
```

And I needed to adjust **settings.py** to specify the template directory:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    ... ... ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template')],
```

Then I saved the actual content in `template/path/to/about_us.html`