# Display static page in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to display contents of a static page in Django project.

urls.py :-

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'spollow.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'index.html'}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

index.html is in the same directory as urls.py

I am getting 500 internal server error. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: is debug on? Can you post the traceback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django static page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123898/django-static-page)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, what is the stacktrace from the 500 error saying that the error may be? You may be using Django 1.6 and the call to direct_to_template is deprecated.

**On Django 1.5 or newer** you can use TemplateView

[Here's the example from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
)
```

You can use the direct_to_template view on Django **1.4 or older**

[Here's the relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$',             direct_to_template, {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
    (r'^foo/(?P<id>\d+)/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'foo_detail.html'}),
)
```

If it is the latter, I would use a module instead of string, (look at the import on the example).

Other than that, without the 500 details it will be shooting in the dark, you may not have the right template, or an incorrect path, or a million different things.

**Bonus note**

If you just want to serve static pages, it might be better to serve them through the actual webserver in front of django (nginx, apache, etc), specially if you are expecting a high volume of traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If Your error is due to unable to find `index.html`

#### if yours is an `app`(ie: created by `python manage.py startapp <app>`) then:

Then `django` will search for template files in `<app>/templates` directory, if you added the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

so you need to create a folder `templates` inside your `<app>` and put `index.html` inside it.

#### if you don't have any `apps`, you want to add the `template path` manually :

open `settings.py`, then edit `TEMPLATE_DIRS`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put the full path of the template dir here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates". 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.5 or newer you can use the `render` function instead of `direct_to_template`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'django.shortcuts.render', {'template_name': 'index.html'}),
)
```

Or if you prefer the more complex way :), you can use class-based `TemplateView`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
)
```