# Export and embed a GitBook into an app or website

Tags: gitbook

I would like to add my book to my website, it's free content, and share it to the viewers of my website.

Is there a way to export Gitbook HTML CSS and JavaScript code and add it to Django?

Answer (score 1):

If your using the legacy cli: running `gitbook build` builds your gitbook into a static site. This static site can then be hosted through Django using this answer ([Django static page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123898/django-static-page)).

Otherwise if your using gitbook.com it appears that they only support pdf exporting (https://docs.gitbook.com/features/pdf-export). This can be statically hosted too if you please, but given your use case I'd look at a static site generator which converts markdown into a blog or website. This can be statically hosted on Django using the same method as above.

Comment: Also if you choose the PDF route: take a look at pandoc (https://pandoc.org/) for converting PDF documents to many formats including HTML.

Comment: Export to PDF is a premium feature, and the result is not guaranteed. 
Unless anybody had concrete luck with that?

Answer (score 0):

The only viable way I found to bring Gitbook content within the main project website (i.e. https://myproject.com/docs) is ripping the Gitbook HTML content with **wget**

```
 wget -p -r -l10 -E -k -nH "https://my-gitbook-project"
```

And later host it as static pages.

The resulting HTML may need some tweaks.

### Drawbacks

- If you have content in multiple branches in multiple "spaces", then the branch selector will need to be replaced.
- Even after wget, it's still a client-rendered ReactJS website, so SEO will be anyway inferior.

At the moment wget is the best workaround for Gitbook explicit refusal to implement subdirectory integration (i.e. myproject.com/docs, which is much better for SEO) as opposed to subdomain integration (i.e. docs.myproject.com).

Personally, I'm seriously considering migrating my documentation away from Gitbook at this point. Even if the two-way-sync with Github is very convenient.