# Django : Edit main.html to reference static webpage

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I am still very new to it so I don't yet understand how all the pieces fit together.

I have successfully built the polls application on the tutorial website (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/) and a 'Hello World!' app as an additional test.  I have created a main page at the root with links to these two applications.  Code for this is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>B. Rabbit</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Applications</h3>

    <ul>
        <li><p><a href="/polls">A Polls Application.</a></p></li>
        <li><p><a href="/hello">Hello World App.</a></p></li>
        <li><p></p><a href="/HWFolder/HWPage.htm">Hello World stand-alone page.</a></p></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I now want to create a new folder in my project with a static webpage (just a simple html file) and add a link to my main page that will point to this static webpage.  That is, rather the create an app via `python manage.py startapp hello`, I want to just create a raw `.html` file, stick it in a folder somewhere, and then point to this. But I don't know how to do this.

The third list object above is my attempt, but this produces a 404 Page not found error.

Below is the `urls.py` script for the website.  I was able to get the Hello World app working by following the syntax for the polls app, but I do not know how to edit this to just refer to a stand-alone page.

```
import os
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.static import serve
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

# Up two folders to serve "site" content
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'site')


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on what scripts I need to edit or how I adjust the site's `urls.py` to refer to a stand-alone page, let's say `HWPage.htm` in the folder `/HWFolder`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123898/django-static-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a link to a standalone HTML page in Django without creating a separate app, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a folder called "static" in the root directory of your Django project (the same level as the manage.py file).
2. Inside the "static" folder, create another folder called "HWFolder".
3. Place your HTML file "HWPage.htm" inside the "HWFolder".
4. In your Django project's `urls.py` file, add the following import at the top:

   ```py
   from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
   ```
5. Modify the `urlpatterns` list to include a new path for serving the static HTML file:

   ```py
   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
       path('hello/', include('hello.urls')),
       path('HWFolder/HWPage.htm', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='HWFolder/HWPage.htm')),
   ]
   ```
6. Save the changes and run your Django development server.

Now, when you visit the URL `/HWFolder/HWPage.htm`, Django will serve the "HWPage.htm" file from the static folder.

Make sure that your Django project's `settings.py` file includes the following configuration for serving static files:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

This allows Django to find and serve static files from the "static" folder.

Remember to restart the Django development server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you.  I get an error saying: TemplateDoesNotExist at /HWFolder/HWPage.htm.  Anything I missed?